# Retrieve a database data based on another column

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[image]

I have columns `Number` and `College` in my database. What I'm trying to do is get the `Number` column based on my `College` column. For example, I have my combobox and if I select "SCITECH" then it will get all the `Number`s of "SCITECH" people.

I tried to using this code but I can't retrieve the numbers.

```
 If Form1.TextBox1UN.Text = "admin" Then
                 Query = "Select * from database.students"

            Else
                Query = "Select * from database.students where College ='" & Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "'"
                COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)

                reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read

                    ComboBox3.Items.Add("Number")
```

Comment: Are you using this code in a separate form? I notice that you use `Form1.TextBox1UN` but `ComboBox3` without the `Form1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is how you would get the value for Number, X is the ordinal position in the select statement. You should not use SELECT * but instead SELECT Number

```
While reader.Read
    ComboBox3.Items.Add(reader.GetInt32(X))
End While
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks For the response. What do you mean by the oridinal position in the select statement? I dont get it.

Comment: Using SELECT Number, College. Number is ordinal position 0 while College is ordinal position 1. So get get Number reader.GetInt32(0)

Comment: I try this Query = "SELECT Number from database.students " then     ComboBox3.Items.Add(reader.GetInt32(0)) but my combobox still not populated. Am i doing it right?

Comment: If no rows were returned from the select statement then the loop would not execute. Test this by executing reader.HasRows which is done after ExecuteReader and before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you ought to do in your code to make it more robust and reliable. It may seem like a lot of bother, but it is worth doing.

First, you should check that there is a SelectedValue by checking the SelectedIndex.

Then, you should use a parameterised query, which means you put placeholders in the query text and add in the values later as parameters. The reason for that is that you do not have to worry about things like escaping apostrophes, and makes it more secure against SQL injection attacks.

You should take care to `.Dispose()` of objects which expose that method so that the framework can take care of cleaning up things for you. Otherwise you can get memory leaks, files left open by mistake, or run out of database connections, as some examples. The `Using` construct will do that for you, also you can use the `Finally` clause of a `Try...Catch` construct.

I don't have MySql to test with, but the following should be a good approximation of what you need:

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On
' ....'
Sub x()
    If Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        ' nothing is selected.
        ' Take the appropriate action
    End If

    Dim collegeName = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim query = "Select `Number` from database.students where College = @CollegeName"
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, dbconn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@CollegeName", .DbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = collegeName})

        Try
            dbconn.Open()
            Dim numbers As New List(Of Object)
            Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While reader.Read()
                numbers.Add(reader.GetInt32(0).ToObject())
            End While

            ComboBox3.Items.AddRange(numbers.ToArray())

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving from database:" & ex.Message)
        Finally
            If dbconn IsNot Nothing Then
                dbconn.Close()
                dbconn.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try

    End Using

End Sub
```

You will need to make additions to the code to allow for the "admin" case too.